# HTC Chacha showing landscape although portrait is set in the manifest file

Tags: android

I was developing an app today and I set the orientation for the all the activities to `portrait` in the manifest file.Now when I deployed the app on my `Xperia U` mobile it was working fine . But when I deployed it in my friends `htc Chacha` it was showing the layout not in portrait.Instead the   layout was shown in `landscape`.

Why this is happening?

Comment: Had the same issue a while back with this device. Unfortunately, my solution was to special case it. Sorry I don't have anything more elegant. Look on the bright side; hardly anyone uses it! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because HTC ChaCha's screen is landscape by default - meaning when you're holding the phone in portrait mode (with keyboard down) the screen orientation for Android is actually set to landscape mode not portraid as it is on other phones. The version of Android OS installed on the device is modified to reflect that.

That's why you're seeing a discrepancy in behaviour.

Comment: so how can I change it to show in portrait mode. is there any option or something ?

Comment: how can i run my app in portrait mode in htc chacha